# What is the difference between varchar(3) and varchar(300)

Tags: mysql

We know that varchar is a variable length data type then  what is the difference between varchar(3) and varchar(300) in mysql ???

Comment: 297 characters.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you seriously not understand the difference between 3 and 300?

Comment: Suppose I want to insert a single character in my column in that scenario what is difference between both ?? Why we use varchar(1) why not varchar(100)??

Answer (score 3):

In SQL `varchar` is a string which varies in length. Traditionally, you specify an upper limit for this string. Here are some things to know about `varchar`:

- Strings which are shorter than the specified limit do not take extra space: they only take up the required space.
- If the string is longer than the limit, the whole record is rejected,  both when you try to `INSERT` a record, and when you try to `UPDATE` a record.
- Traditionally the *upper* upper limit was 255 characters. Modern databases no longer have this limit.
- Some databases, such as PostgreSQL recommend that you no longer specify the length this way. Instead they recommend an unlimited string (`varchar` without the length) and limit it using a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` instead.
- Most modern databases handle strings much more efficiently than in the past, so there is less need to be restrictive about the size of the string.

The short answer to your question is that both `varchar(3)` and `varchar(300)` are limited-length strings, and both will allow shorter strings without penalty. However clearly one is *much* shorter than the other.

Comment: Note that [MySQL ignores `CHECK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-indexes-keys).

Comment: @Schwern I hadn’t realised that. I find that it will be supported in the up coming 10.2 release of MariaDB, which is yet another reason to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Manngo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43422663/14660), `varchar(300)` has an extra byte of overhead than `varchar(3)` because its max is over 255. From [the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html)...

> In contrast to CHAR, VARCHAR values are stored as a 1-byte or 2-byte length prefix plus data. The length prefix indicates the number of bytes in the value. A column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255 bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes.

Basically, the length of the string must be stored. 1 byte can only hold 0 to 255, so 2 bytes are required to store a length that can go up to 300.

> *Suppose I want to insert a single character in my column in that scenario what is difference between both ?? Why we use varchar(1) why not varchar(100)??*

If the column is only supposed to ever store a single character, use `char(1)`, a single byte, to ensure the integrity of the data (`varchar(1)` is two bytes). That ensures anyone using the column will only ever get what they expect and don't have to do their own data validation.

Since the size of a `varchar` is only a max, specifying a smaller one won't make the table use any less disk (except as noted above about >255). Avoid adding arbitrary limits and business rules to your columns. For example, if you're going to store a URL or email address, there's little reason not to allow `varchar(255)`. Limits based on business rules and UX concerns should be handed at a higher layer and not limited by the database schema.